# How to send exe file in telegram bot from url

Tags: telegram-bot

I can't send exe files in telegram bot
for example this is 7z download link : http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1604-x64.exe

```
https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendDocument?chat_id=chatId&document=http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1604-x64.exe
```

When i send this file return me :

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}
```

it is possibile send exe file in telegram bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Let's see to [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files):

> Sending by URL: n sendDocument, sending by URL will currently only work for gif, pdf and zip files.

You can't send `.exe` file by URL. Instead of sending by url, in your case you need to

> Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files.